# Bulk API Query Job in Apex with big response

Tags: apex, callout, bulk-api, migration, httpresponse

I have a task to query a million records from one org and then upsert them in another org. I use a Bulk API query job to get all records.

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('callout:OrgIntegration/services/data/v58.0/jobs/query/id/results?locator=MTAwMDA&maxRecords=1000000');
request.setMethod('GET');
request.setHeader('Accept', 'text/csv');
request.setHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip');
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
```

But I have the error: "Apex heap size is too large".
I need that CSV to pass it to another Bulk API job - to insert records (also in Apex).
So can you please give me any ideas for how I can deal with that large response?

Answer (score 1):

SFDX to the rescue !

bulk export:

```
sf data query -o source.org -q "your query" -b -r csv -w 10 > records.csv
```

bulk import:

```
sf data upsert bulk -o target.org --external-id [your external id field api name] -f records.csv -s [your sobject name] -w 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Apex is not the right tool for this, as it is not designed to handle such a large amount of CSV data (hence why you are getting an error).

I would suggest using Salesforce Data Loader if this job can be done manually. Otherwise something like a function in AWS Lambda could handle this use case.

Alternatively, you could use Salesforce Connect to view the records in one org from another org, if that works with your use-cases.

Comment: Initially this insertion of records should occur by clicking on the quick action. so i decided to use apex. 
how can i do this if not manually?

Comment: How many times do you need to do this migration? If just once, you can query all records in one org using Salesforce Data Loader and then use that result to insert the records into the second org.

Comment: not just once. i need to query that million of records from second org then compare with records on the firs org and upsert them.

Comment: does this need to happen automatically? how often will this comparison and upsert need to happen?

Comment: not automatically. when the user clicks on quick action like once a day

Comment: Ok, in that case I would recommend a button that does a callout to a service that will move the data for you. I personally would use AWS lambda and the JSforce library, but there are other options available.

Comment: okay thank you!

Comment: Is Salesforce Connect an option for you? That might be a better solution than syncing the data every day. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.xorg_setup.htm&type=5